# How to select component from drop down in navbar Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, header, angular6, navbar

How to dropdown select to a particular component. The problem is that the Header component has no connection to that component. Look my folder structure

```
//app component 
<app-header></app-header>
<ng-snotify></ng-snotify> 
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>

//this is my header component
//countries is array which has countries and with ngIf i change only only 
//content in component

<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a routerLink="home">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a routerLink="services">SERVICES</a></li>
    <li><a routerLink="jobs">JOBS</a></li>
    <li><a routerLink="teams">TEAM</a></li>
    <li><a routerLink="contact-us">
      <select (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
        <option>CONTACT US</option>
          <option  *ngFor="let coun of countries">{{ coun }} </option>
      </select>
    </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>


onChange(selectedCountry: string) {
      this.countrySelect = selectedCountry;
}
```

The problem is the no relation between the header navbar component and contact us component and I cannot from the navbar dropdown to switch the content that I ngFor. How can I solve this?

Comment: you can create navbar service that contains a property let say ```selectedCountry```. include that service in both header and navbar component. change  value of ```selectedCountry``` in navbar component will update the value of ```selectedCountry``` in header component as well

Comment: create service and my function onChange set in service and also array countries and variable countrySelect, Okey that I know do?  But how after use that(string which country is selected) in my Contactus component?

Comment: you can include navbarservice in you contactus component as well and use that property

Comment: you can use this service in any component that want to access or change ```selectedCountry``` property. if any component update this property it will be updated every where this property is used

Comment: How I create function onChange in Service when I need parameter from template? Look my code
in header


this.countrySelect = this.ctry.onChange(selectedCountry); //problemisselectedCountry parameter



in service


  onChange(selectedCountry: string) {
    let countrySelect = null;
    countrySelect = selectedCountry;
    return countrySelect;
    // console.log(countrySelect)
}

Comment: Data which I get is from template header. onChange function is on service but i think not read parameter...